# Orange border around a div in a phonegap app

Tags: html, css, cordova, phonegap-build

Hi I've button which is created using rounded div and font awesome icon, But whenever user tap on the icon it's highlighted with orange square border. I am unable to under stand where the problem is.

Kindly check in the attached image! Please help

[image: Issue is highlighted]

Comment: Could be the browser's user agent styles (which you may not be able to change), or it could be some custom CSS. Hard to say from a photo.

Comment: Hi @isherwood it's the first time I am experiencing this behavior. earlier I used jQueryMobile and didn't get such output

Answer (score 1):

You need to develop your CSS style more for than button. Just like when you use :hover. You need to set the Selector for the click. See these CSS buttons for an example on how to do it: https://github.com/alexwolfe/Buttons